# quartz job schedular not working as OSGI bundle

Tags: java, maven, quartz-scheduler, osgi-bundle, karaf

My code contains the basic exmaple of quartz schedular.. In normal java application its running but when Im converting it as a bundle and deploying it in karaf its not working.

```
    @Component
    @Service
    public class testImpl implements testI {
    @Override
    public void test() {
    System.out.println("testImpl started");
    try {

        JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(TestJob.class)
            .withIdentity("testJob")
            .build();
        System.out.println("job \n");

        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
              .withSchedule(  
                    SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                    .withIntervalInSeconds(5)
                    .repeatForever())  
                         .build();  

        System.out.println("trigger \n ");

    //THIS PARTICULAR LINE ONWARDS THE CODE IS NOT EXCUTING IM NOT GETTING SYSOUT AFTER THIS LINE.  
    SchedulerFactory schFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    System.out.println("scheduler \n");
        Scheduler sch = schFactory.getScheduler();


        sch.start();            
        sch.scheduleJob(job, trigger);      

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Schedular is throwing exceptions like

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.<init>(StdSchedulerFactory.java:298)
at com.ericsson.testImpl.testImpl.test(testImpl.java:77)
at com.ericsson.testConsumer.testConsumer.bindTestI(testConsumer.java:27)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
```

but as far as I know Karaf has a inbuilt support for slf4j. No need of explicitly adding slf4j bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out root cause of the error. In Quartz jar pom.xml the slf4j dependency version was 1.6.1 and my Karaf-2.3.3 inbuilt slf4j dependency is 1.6.6. Changing the quartz pom with the correct version for dependencies helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure, you miss an import in your Manifest.MF file.

Open the Manifest of your bundle, at the "Import-Package" section there should be org.slf4j. It seems you are missing to import the package.

```
 Import-Package: .....,org.slfj,....
```

If you use the maven-bundle-plugin, extend your configuration:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <instructions>
            <Import-Package>org.slf4j</Import-Package>
          </instructions>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

If this answer didn't help, add the full stack trace and the output of mvn dependency:tree to your question.

Comment: Ok, a copy of mvn dependency:tree + Manifest would help next time :)